# I am adding a textfield dynamically via jQuery and id of text field is not incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am copying a textfield but its id is not increment. Is there any other way to create a specific id after copying a textfield

```js
$(function(){
  $('#idbtn').click(function(){
    $('#Institute').clone().attr('id','Institute_' + $(this).index()).insertAfter('#Institute');
  });//click
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text"  id="Institute"> 
<input type="button" id="idbtn" value="add"/>
```

Comment: But id is incrementing.

Comment: Institute_0 is showing in console for every textfield

Comment: Right here if I inspect elements I see incrementing id's e.g. `Institute_3`

Comment: its fine now .. declared a variable and now its working . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a separate variable and increment that each time the function is called. jQuery's `.index()` is a DOM search, not what you want at all.

```js
  $(function() {
    var i = 0; // inside the closure
    $('#idbtn').click(function() {
      $('#Institute').clone().attr('id', 'Institute_' + ++i).insertAfter('#Institute');
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="Institute">DIV</div>

<button id="idbtn">click me</button>
```